# visit next page with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to go next by clicking Next button (right arrow >) from keyboard.
How can I do that?
I found a solution, but failed before succeeding 100%.

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.hotkeys.js"></script>
        <script>
            //This page is a result of an autogenerated content made by running test.html with firefox.
            function domo() {
                jQuery(document).bind('keydown', 'right', function (evt) {
                    location.href = $('#previous_page_link').href;
                    //window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
                });
            }
            jQuery(document).ready(domo);
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a id="previous_page_link" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
        <a id="next_page_link" href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
    </body>

</html>
```

https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery(document).bind('keydown', 'right', function () {
          location.href = $('#previous_page_link').attr('href');
       });
   });
```

Comment: Why does that need to bound in a `document.ready` ? You're binding the event to the document itself.

Comment: He is using hotkeys plugin which does the right arrow key check for him.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder to wait for the DOM to be ready before attaching events.

Comment: thanks, it's working fine. i tested it different browser. working on ie789, ff, chrome, opera on windows 7. thanks.

Comment: @Vega Right. I'm catching up with new technologies :)

Comment: @VisioN tbh, I would do the check myself instead of relying on a plugin for simple stuff.

Comment: @rahim701 any time, you can accpet it as anwser